# Memory utilization in taurus based on PID

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, perfmon, taurus

I have an scenario were i need to get the Memory based on PID in Taurus.
I got an CPU utilization based on PID using code in Metices like this:

```
cpu:pid=4656:percent
```

How to get the Memory utilization using the PID?
I tried:

```
mem:pid=4656:percent
```

But it's giving an error:

> item = {x: float(values.pop(0)) for x in self._result_fields}
>   ValueError: could not convert string to float: